# Function that checks multiple combinations of operations between columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, function, combinations, apply

Here is a sample of the original dataframe (data provided at the end)

```
> DATA
     N_b N_l  A   x.sqr_sum  e_1  e_2  e_3   e_4   e_5   e_6 e_7 e_8 
1    7   6   -36      4032   33.8 21.8  9.8  -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   0   0 
2    7   4   -27      2268   23.6 11.6 -0.4 -12.4   0.0   0.0   0   0 
3    7   4   -27      2268   23.6 11.6 -0.4 -12.4   0.0   0.0   0   0 
4    7   6   -36      4032   33.8 21.8  9.8  -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   0   0 
5    7   6   -36      4032   33.8 21.8  9.8  -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   0   0 
6    7   6   -36      4032   33.8 21.8  9.8  -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   0   0 
7    7   8   -45      6300   44.0 32.0 20.0   8.0  -4.0 -16.0 -28 -40 
8    7   8   -45      6300   44.0 32.0 20.0   8.0  -4.0 -16.0 -28 -40 
9    7   8   -45      6300   44.0 32.0 20.0   8.0  -4.0 -16.0 -28 -40
```

I want to write a function to calculate `R` from the equation

[image]

I write the code below to calculate `R` and the `N_l` responsible for the maximum `R`.

```
R <- function(x){
  N_b <- x[1]
  N_l <- x[2]
  N_l_seq <- seq(N_l)
  A <- x[3]
  x.sqr_sum <- x[4]
  e <- x[5:12]
  m <- Multi.Presence$m[N_l_seq]
  f <- m * (N_l_seq/N_b + A * cumsum(e) / x.sqr_sum)
  c(val = max(f), pos = which.max(f))
}

DATA <- cbind(DATA, vars = t(apply(DATA, 1, R)))
```

In the function above, `R` is calculated for all possible values of `N_l` by defining `N_l_seq <- seq(N_l)`. The problem is I don't want to just multiply by `cumsum(e)` as written in the function. I want to modify it so that it would calculate `R` for all possible combinations for the same number of `e_1, e_2, e_3,...` as the current value of `N_l`.

**Example**

If `N_l = 3`, the equation for `f` is calculated for the `cumsum` of all possible combinations of 3 of the `e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5, e_6, e_7, e_8`, such as `cumsum(e_1, e_8, e_6)` and `cumsum(e_7, e_2, e_4)`. When `N_l = 5`, the equation for `f` is calculated for the `cumsum` of all possible combinations of 5 of the `e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5, e_6, e_7, e_8`, and so on.

**PROBLEM**

I am not sure how to update the `f` equation so instead of the `cumsum()` of all the possible `e` values, it calculates the `cumsum()` of all combinations of a number equal to the current `N_l` of the `e` values.

**DATA**

```
> dput(DATA)
structure(list(N_b = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), N_l = c(6, 
4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8), A = c(-36, -27, -27, -36, -36, -36, 
-45, -45, -45), x.sqr_sum = c(4032, 2268, 2268, 4032, 4032, 4032, 
6300, 6300, 6300), e_1 = c(33.8, 23.6, 23.6, 33.8, 33.8, 33.8, 
44, 44, 44), e_2 = c(21.8, 11.6, 11.6, 21.8, 21.8, 21.8, 32, 
32, 32), e_3 = c(9.8, -0.399, -0.399, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 20, 20, 20), 
e_4 = c(-2.2, -12.4, -12.4, -2.2, -2.2, -2.2, 8, 8, 8), e_5 = 
c(-14.2, 0, 0, -14.2, -14.2, -14.2, -4, -4, -4), e_6 = c(-26.2, 
0, 0, -26.2, -26.2, -26.2, -16, -16, -16), e_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -28, -28, -28), e_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -40, -40, -40), 
S = c(12, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 
4L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 199L, 200L, 201L), class = "data.frame")
```

A dependent variable `m` is defined in the dataframe below:

```
> dput(Multi.Presence)
structure(list(N_l = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), m = c(1.2, 
1, 0.85, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you mean permutation or combination?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding combination! I will change that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want. I guess you should use `combn` rather than `cumsum` in your function `R`.

- As the first step, I merged `Multi.Presence` to `DATA` so you can read the corresponding value of `m` with respect to `N_l`

```
df <- merge(DATA, Multi.Presence, by = "N_l")
```

- Then, I rewrote function `R` such that it accepts the rows of `df` as the argument

```
R <- function(x){
  N_l <- x["N_l"]
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l_seq <- seq(N_l)
  A <- x["X_ext"]
  x.sqr_sum <- x["x.sqr_sum"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]
  m <- x["m"]
  f <- m * (N_l/N_b + A * combn(e,N_l,sum) / x.sqr_sum)
  c(val = max(f), pos = which.max(f))
}
```

- Finally, you can execute function `R` within `apply` by rows, e.g.,

```
> apply(df,1,R)
          [,1]       [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
val  0.4704685  0.4704685  0.7475  0.7475  0.7475  0.7475 0.6685714 0.6685714
pos 56.0000000 56.0000000 28.0000 28.0000 28.0000 28.0000 1.0000000 1.0000000
         [,9]
val 0.6685714
pos 1.0000000
```

---

**Update**

I have no clue how you want to deal with the `combn`, but below is an update

```
R <- function(x){
  # browser()
  N_l <- x["N_l"]
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l_seq <- seq(N_l)
  A <- x["A"]
  x.sqr_sum <- x["x.sqr_sum"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]
  m <- Multi.Presence$m[N_l_seq]
  f <- m * sapply(N_l_seq,function(k) N_l/N_b + A * max(combn(e,k,sum)) / x.sqr_sum)
  c(val = max(f), pos = which.max(f))
}
```

Comment: So I can see how you used `combn` and it is exactly what I wanted. But the reason that I did not merge the multi.presence dataframe with DATA was that I am looking at all values in `N_l_seq`. I tried running the code but I get the error that "Error in combn(e, N_l_seq, sum) : length(m) == 1L is not TRUE"

Comment: So In my code I am keeping `m` in the different dataframe and changing the line you provided with `combn(e,N_l_seq,sum)` so I don't know how to do this within the function

Comment: @MaralDorri What do you mean "But the reason that I did not merge the multi.presence dataframe with DATA was that I am looking at all values in N_l_seq"? I am a bit confused since you said in your post that you pick `N_l` out of 8 to sum.

Comment: `N_l` is a singular number for example 5. I want to calculate `R` for all values in `seq(N_l)`. Since `m` is dependent on `N_l` I kept it as a different dataframe. So that in each iteration of `N_l_seq = c(1,2,3,4,5)` it chooses the correct `m` value. Similarly, I want the `combn` function to us the itteration of `N_l_seq` each time. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that I could write a function within another. The calculated `R` values are larger than anticipated and I wanted to clarify something. The `pos = which.max(f))` the term is supposed to tell me which term in the `N_l_seq` was responsible for the `max(f)`, but I am getting larger numbers like 30 and 25 for this position output and the `N_l` values are all smaller than 10

Comment: @MaralDorri Let's say, if `N_l_seq` is from `1` to `5`, we should go through `1` to `5` to have five `m` values. Am I right? In that case, you compute `combn(e,1,sum)`, `combn(e,2,sum)`, ...., `combn(e,5,sum)`, but each of them is an array. How do you bring those arrays to `f`?

Comment: @MaralDorri See my update. I think you equation is vague, I assume you want to find out the max value among all combinations.